# Where do you purchase Fighter and Fighter Bomber BPOs in Eve Online?

Tags: eve-online

Which stations do you go to for purchasing fighter and fighter bomber blueprints from NPC sellers in eve online? I'm aware they're on the market in Jita, but I want to know which NPC stations are the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've been able to find, these are sold only by the **CreoDron** corporation.

Their closest station to Jita is, I believe, in the Ikami system -- only eight jumps away. You can find the [list of their other stations here](http://evemaps.dotlan.net/npc/CreoDron/stations).